# How to remove all non Hebrew characters from a string and put the words into an array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, regex, string

I want to remove all non-Hebrew characters from a string (including numbers and special characters).
For example:
myString = "/43davcשלום דד";

I need the string to only be the Hebrew characters with spaces: "שלום דד".
I also would like to put all the words from the string into an array of Strings.

I tried to use Regex but I can't make it work...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want regular expressions, you can use [Character classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions).

```
string myString = "/43davcשלום דד";

var result = Regex.Replace(myString, @"\P{IsHebrew}", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code. Have the alphabet and check each Letter to see if it is Hebrew.

```
string hebrewAlphabet = "אבגדהוזחטיכךלמנסעפצקרשתםןףץ";

string FilterText (string input){
     string output = "";

     foreach (char letter in input){
        if (hebrewAlphabet.indexOf( letter ) > 0){
            output += letter;
        }
     }

     return ouput;
|
```